# Need reference to custom UITableViewCell inside UITextField delegate method in Swift without using the tag property

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate

I have a custom UITableViewCell in my UITableView that contains multiple UITextFields.  My ViewController that contains my tableView implements UITextFieldDelegate.  This means that the UITextField delegate methods are triggered when the user is interacting with the textFields.

My problem is that I need to access the textFields that are contained inside the custom UITableViewCell from inside the UITextField delegate methods.  The challenge is this: unfortunately, I am unable to use the "tag" property that the UITextField has. The "tag" property is being used for something else, and at this point in the project I unfortunately can't refactor it.

For example, in the following delegate method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //instead of: if textField.tag == someNumber
    //I would like to have something like:
    //if textField == cell.textFieldA {
    //...
    //} else if textField == cell.textFieldB {
    //...
    //}
...
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest that your cell subclass should implement the textfield delegate and pass relevant events back to your view controller via another delegate protocol

Comment: This occurred to me (i.e. letting my cell subclass implement the UITextFieldDelegate), but I wasn't sure how to link the events from the cell subclass with the UIViewController which contains the UITableView.

Comment: Have the view controller implement your new protocol (that you define) and it sets itself as the cell's delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an extension of UITextField. something like this:

```
extension UITextField {

  private struct AssociatedKeys {

    static var someId = "someId"

  }

  @IBInspectable var someId: String? {

    get {

      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.someId) as? String

    }

    set {

      if let newValue = newValue {

        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.someId, newValue as NSString?, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Then you can access and compare:

```
textField.someId
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt answer.  Can you please elaborate on your solution as to what it is you're doing?

Comment: I think I got it.  What you're doing is attaching another property to UITextField that functions the same way as the "tag" property, correct?

Comment: yes correct. you just have to adjust the type of the variable that you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. i have tried it in Objective C

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:textField.superview.superview.center];

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.txt1 is your textfield Object
if(textField == cell.txt1)
{

}
```

You can convert it in swift.